# I cannot create any more admin user accounts

Tags: users

Can it be that I have hit a limit for amount of admin users? I have only 6 now and I would like to add 3 more. But when I try to set a new one up, it cannot send the verification email.

If I try to resend verification, then an internal server error pops up with the message "Could not instantiate mail function."

Does this mean my server is the issue?

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

josh

Comment: Did you set up the first 6 admin accounts with the site already being hosted on that server? So there didn't change anything with server setup, mail config?

Answer (score 2):

> Could not instantiate mail function.

That error means that the [PHP mail](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is not installed and/or configured for use on the server you're currently on.

You can either configure that to properly work, or go under Settings->Email and choose another mail delivery option that does work for you.